# Image Upload with ASP.Net Core MVC and Azure (Blob)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm developing my first website for my college homework, using ASP.Net Core MVC.
What i have to do is build a website that allows people to upload images, and these images must be saved as a Blob in Azure.

What i did in my cshtml is:

```
            <label>Images</label>
            <input type="file" name="uploadFiles" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" />
```

And in my controller, i did :

```
        public void SaveBlob(IFormFile file, int id, int imageNumber)
        {
            var BlobStorageConnectionString = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build()["BlobStorageConnectionString"];
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(BlobStorageConnectionString, "data");
            string fileName = id.ToString() + "_" + imageNumber.ToString() + ".jpg";

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                blobClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, ms);
            }
        }
```

This is not working, i'm not getting an error, but the file is not being saved in my Container in Azure.

I tried to do something different with a file that was already saved in my computer, and it's worked fine:

```
            var bc = new BlobClient(BlobStorageConnectionString, "data", fileName);
            bc.Upload(@"C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\20221206181503496.jpg");
```

Can someone help how to fix it, please?

Thanks!

```
                                                                             .
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: `file.CopyTo(ms);` <-- This is unnecessary: you're wasting RAM by loading the entire file into memory. Instead you can pass `file.OpenReadStream()` to `UploadBlobAsync`.

Comment: The bug is that you aren't using `await` on `UploadBlobAsync`: so the upload will _start_ and then yield control back to your `SaveBlob` and then end-up nowhere because the `Task` is never awaited (I forget _exactly_ how ASP.NET Core handles this situation, but you shouldn't be in that situation in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

The most plausible reason is that you used `blobClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, ms);` in a non-async method

try this

```
public async Task SaveBlob(IFormFile file, int id, int imageNumber)
{
    var BlobStorageConnectionString = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build()["BlobStorageConnectionString"];
    var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(BlobStorageConnectionString, "data");
    string fileName = id.ToString() + "_" + imageNumber.ToString() + ".jpg";

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        await blobClient.UploadBlobAsync(fileName, ms);
    }
}
```

be sure to await SaveBlob also

Comment: And `SaveBlob()` should be renamed to `SaveBlobAsync()` and should accept a `CancellationToken` too.